# Keycloak - URL Reset Password email behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, keycloak

We are using **Keycloak 2.0.0.Final** installed behind a **nginx proxy** on a RedHat environment.

We are currently facing a problem with the ***Reset Password*** functionality which send an email with the internal server host instead of the external one in the action URL as we are behind a proxy.

I receive this by email: https://internal/auth/realms/MYREALM/login-actions/reset-credentials?code=wYhHP(...) but the end user should see https://external/auth/realms/MYREALM/login-actions/reset-credentials?code=wYhHP(...). The whole proxy settings work perfectly otherwise, it's basically an URL rewriting function.

I found this ticket relating a similar case but the solution isn't ideal: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-October/003428.html

Any hidden properties, settings we could use or solution to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nginx sets the emailed URL prefix from the contents of the Host header, so your nginx proxy needs to be configured to pass the Host header intact.

Something like this:

```
proxy_pass        <your internal keycloak URL or IP address>
...
proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
...
```

You may also need to set `X-forwarded-proto` if your internal URL is not https