# Keycloak Verification Link contains Private IP address

Tags: authentication, jboss, keycloak, keycloak-services

Our Application service is using Keycloak's Admin REST APIs to create user and to send verification email.

In this setup, both application service and Keycloak are hosted in private IP address( in AWS private subnet ). On this setup, Keycloak is sending verification email but the verification link contains private IP address !!!

Question : How can we configure Keycloak so that it will send public IP address (or fixed load balancer domain ) ?

Our setup is :
                        User Portal Application
                             |
                         AWS Load balancer
                             |
Application -------------> Keycloak
[Private]    [Keycloak 
             Admin 
             REST API]

Note : When the same keycloak is accessed from public IP (via load balancer),  Keycloak is sending email with load balancer domain - properly as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [KeyCloak Forgot password Email link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181881/keycloak-forgot-password-email-link)

Comment: Thank you. it helped and solved  my issue - by adding "header=x-forwarded-host= <External Host>" header.