# How to use method with generics and inheritance?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Having the following classes:

```
public interface Step<C extends Config> {
  void setConfig(C config);
}
```

and

```
public class ValidationStep implements Step<ValidationConf> {
  public void setConfig(ValidationConf conf) {}
  // implementation
}
```

and

```
public class ProcessStep implements Step<ProcessConf> {
  public void setConfig(ProcessConf conf) {}
  // implementation
}
```

and

```
public interface Config {
  Class<? extends Step> type();
}
```

and

```
public class ValidationConf implements Config {
  public Class<? extends Step> type() {
    return ValidationStep.class;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class ProcessConf implements Config {
  public Class<? extends Step> type() {
    return ProcessStep.class;
  }
}
```

so, the application needs to dynamically instantiate Step subclasses objects, set the configuration accordingly and run the step, like this.

```
List<Config> configs = loadConfigsFromRepository(); // contain all subtypes of Config
for (Config conf: configs) {
  Step<? extends Config> step = conf.type().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();

  step.setConfig(conf); // compiler complains

}
```

Error message:

> "The method setConfig(capture#8-of ? extends Config) in the type
> Step<capture#8-of ? extends Config> is not applicable for the
> arguments (Config)".

Checking the documentation, looks like Java won´t be friendly in this case:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html

What are the possible solutions to overcome this code restriction `step.setConfig(conf);`?

**EDITED [SOLUTION]**

Code can be viewed here: https://github.com/danieldestro/cucumber-salad/tree/generics/src/main/java/my/generics

Comment: What does "compiler complains" mean, exactly? what is the error message?

Comment: "The method setConfig(capture#8-of ? extends Config) in the type Step<capture#8-of ? extends Config> is not applicable for the arguments (Config)"

Comment: Your `StepConfig` class is missing from your example.

Comment: You're trying to dynamically assign an unknown `Config` to its `Step` without knowing it. Since generics is a compile-time thing, that won't work.

Comment: What is *`Context`* in *`Step.run(Context ctx)`*? It magically appears again out of nowhere in your *`for`* loop: „*`step.run(context)`*“. How does it get there? You don't make that clear.

Comment: Just put that `context` is provided before that code snippet... it is irrelevant for the question here.

Comment: Also, you define a generic class: „*`Step< C extends Config >`*“. But then in *`Config`* you specify the method that uses it, to use a raw type: „*`Class<? extends Step> type();`*“. Why is that? Not relevant for the question?

Comment: „*...it is irrelevant for the question here...*“ — Have you considered removing it from the question in that case?

Answer (score 2):

Because *`Step.setConfig( Config )`* is a „*consumer*“, one way to resolve the „*`is not applicable for the arguments (Config)`*“ error you get is to [*use a lower bound like I demonstrate here*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/19m)…

```
…  
List< ? extends Config > configs = loadConfigsFromRepository( ); // contain all subtypes of Config
  
for ( Config conf: configs ) {
    Step< ? super Config > step = conf.type( ).getDeclaredConstructor( ).newInstance( );

      step.setConfig( conf ); // *set* makes Step a „consumer“
}
…
```

That way you don't need the cast that the other answer proposes.

My *`loadConfigsFromRepository( )`* [*is implemented like*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/19m)…

```
static List< ? extends Config > loadConfigsFromRepository(){ 
    
    return of( new ValidationConf( ), new ProcessConf( ) );        
}
```

Comment: If I do this I get: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#8-of ? extends Step<?> to Step<? super Config>". And I don´t see how I can change `interface Step<C extends Config>` to use `super`, because I use `C` to define the `setConfig` method argument.

Comment: „*...I get: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#8-of ? extends Step<?> to Step<? super Config>"...*“ — Where/How did you get that? [*The code I linked to*](https://jdoodle.com/ia/19m) doesn't produce any errors. — „*how I can change `interface Step<C extends Config>` to use `super`*“  — Look at the code in my answer and the code I linked to. I didn't propose you *change `interface Step<C extends Config>` to use `super`*.  The only thing I proposed you change is the „*`Step< ? super Config > step`*“ in the *`for`* loop. What you marked as „*compiler complains*“ in your original Q.

Comment: Yep. I tried it and it works. Thanks! https://github.com/danieldestro/cucumber-salad/tree/generics/src/main/java/my/generics

Comment: Awesome danieldestro! I'm glad I could help you. A more recent answer by @Nikolas [*to a question more recent than yours*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937883/4465539) was just accepted and upvoted. That answer is essentially the same answer that I proposed to you several hours ago. Do you agree or disagree that my answer is a more *acceptable* answer than the other two answers here to *your* question? If you disagree, then can you let me know, please: *In what way could my answer be improved in order for you to have marked it as accepted*? Why is neither of the three acceptable to you? TIA.

Comment: Hi @deduper - I would say both solutions are satisfactory and works fine. I would agree that your solution may seem a bit more elegant to me, avoiding casting, but both are just syntatic sugar.

Comment: „*both are just syntatic sugar…*“ — This is what I was hoping you'd help me understand: @Matthieu was blocked because like you he was not aware of that exact same „*syntatic sugar*“ that you were not aware of previously. Unlike you tho [*he expressed his gratitude for being unblocked*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63937883/4465539) by the exact same *syntactic sugar* that unblocked you. He showed gratitude by ***accepting*** the answer that proposed *syntactic sugar* as the solution to his blocking issue. But you're not grateful enough to express the same gratitude? I'm just curious: *Why Not?*

Comment: „*…personal issues of self esteem…*“ – @danieldestro — How ironic you should say that. Because it's clear that the reason you find it so hard to show gratitude for being unblocked by my *syntactic sugar* gift to you, is because to do so would mean you'd have to admit to yourself that you ***don't*** know everything. And facing up to such a reality is not very appealing to people with „*issues of self esteem*“. People like you, I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the wildcard. You don't need it.

```
Step<Config> step = (Step<Config>) conf.type().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
```

Comment: I get an error: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#7-of ? extends Step<?> to Step<Config>".

Comment: I see. It's because you are getting a granular type from `type()` to `Config`. At this point you can just cast it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah ok! Now with the cast, I only get a warning message: "Type safety: Unchecked cast from capture#7-of ? extends Step<?> to Step<Config>". Let me run and check if it works.

Comment: From what is given, it doesn't matter what type of Config it is, so it's okay to cast away to Config.

Comment: Do you *agree* or *disagree* George, that it's best to avoid explicit casts if *at all* possible? In my opinion applying the *PECS* principal is a better (*i.e. more type safe*) solution to @danieldestro's error. Would that be fair to say?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is not fully correct. I reccomend you not to use `Reflections` until you really need it.

Pay attention, that all these implementation should be hidden inside the package and only `Step` interface should be `public`. `Config` implementation holds all data to create `Step` class, so just delegate it to this.

```
package steps

public interface Step<C extends Config> {
  void run(Context context);
}

private final class ValidationStep implements Step<ValidationConf> {
    private final ValidationConf config;
    
    public ValidationStep(ValidationConf config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

private class ProcessStep implements Step<ProcessConf> {
    private final ProcessConf config;
    
    public ValidationStep(ProcessConf config) {
        this.config = config;
    }    
}

public interface Config {
    
    Step<? extends Config> createStep();
  
}

private class ValidationConf implements Config {
    
    public Step<ValidationConf> createStep() {
        return new ValidationStep(this);
    }
}

private class ProcessConf implements Config {
    public Step<ValidationConf> createStep() {
        return new ProcessConf(this);
    }
}

package foo

List<Config> configs = loadConfigsFromRepository();

for (Config config : loadConfigsFromRepository()) {
  config.createStep().run(context);
}
```