# Tell compiler an <Object> is equivalent to the <?> it wants

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-conversion, wildcard

I have objects that pre-generate some configuration once so they can process computation later on faster (possibly several times). I'm trying to genericize it to avoid passing the configuration as an `Object` and casting it each time.

```
interface IComputable<T> {
    T configure(); // Generate configuration object
    int compute(T conf); // Run the computation based on the pre-generated configuration
    float precision(T conf); // Make the compute() computation finer-grained
    ...
}
```

```
class ComputableInfo {
    IComputable<?> computable;
    Object config; // Real type is <?>
    int result;

    ComputableInfo(String id) {
        computable = ComputableFactory.createFrom(id);
        config = computable.configure();
        result = computable.compute(config); // <<<--- The method compute(capture#3-of ?) in the type TestInterface.IComputable<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)
    }
}
```

I'm getting a compilation error:

> The method compute(capture#3-of ?) in the type TestInterface.IComputable<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Of course, I can replace the `int compute(T conf)` by `int compute(Object conf)` but I would have to explicitly cast it to the appropriate `T`. It's not that big a problem, but it makes the code less obvious.

I could also make the `ComputableInfo` generic with

```
interface ComputableInfo<T> {
    IComputable<T> computable;
    T config;
    ...
```

but that would create compilation problems in some other places (mostly "raw types" warning) that I'd like to avoid more than the previous workaround (using `Object` instead of `T`).

Is there a way to achieve that? I'm even open to turning such problem from error to warning in the compiler settings, or maybe have an extra private method that would return both `config` and `result` in a single object?

EDIT: to add up on the "further compilation problems" if I make `ComputableInfo` generic: I have another method in the interface (see edited) that is called through the `ComputableInfo`:

```
ComputableInfo<?> info = getInfo(id);
info.computable.precision(info.config); // <<<--- (same kind of error)
```

The problem is that the `ComputableInfo` has no way to know the `T` type of `Computable<T>` (or no way I know), as it comes from a Factory that builds it from a configuration file.

Comment: Making the `ComputableInfo` type generic _is_ the correct solution. Fix the other warnings.

Comment: The reason you get that compile error is because an `IComputable<?>` is an `IComputable` that holds some unknown type, and you cannot pass it an arbitrary `Object`, because the compiler has no way to check that that object is of the right type. The same reason as why you cannot add to a `List<?>`, which has been asked and answered many times on SO. You can cast your `IComputable<?>` to `IComputable<Object>` but this is an ugly, and type-unsafe hack.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I have edited to explain further: The "raw types" warnings I get can be removed by parametrizing them with `<?>`, which erases the type and creates errors instead of warnings. I'm still investigating this route though...

Comment: @Jesper indeed I understand why the compiler complains about it. I have detailed a bit more about the Factoy creating the Computables, erasing the parametrization...

Comment: How about `IComputable<? super Object> computable;`?

Comment: @Nikolas right, the error disappears. I thought it was kind of implicit, since *any* object extends `Object` somehow. I'll see how it goes...

Comment: @Nikolas that did the trick! If you could add that as an answer I'd accept it :) And if you can explain *why* I'd upvote it as well :) (or that might be another question...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting an object from a wildcarded type and passing it back to the same object, is a known limitation of the generic type system. E.g., when you have

```java
List<?> list = …
```

you might want to copy an element from one index to another like

```
Object o = list.get(0);
list.set(1, o);
```

but it doesn’t work, even when you avoid the local variable of a non-denotable type. In other words, even the following does not compile:

```
list.set(1, list.get(0));
```

But you can add a generic helper method that does the operation by allowing to capture the wildcard type in a type parameter for the duration of the operation:

```java
static <T> void copyFromTo(List<T> l, int from, int to) {
    l.set(to, l.get(from));
}
```

```java
List<?> list = …
copyFromTo(list, 0, 1); // now works
```

---

You can apply this pattern to your case as well:

```java
class ComputableInfo {
    IComputable<?> computable;
    Object config; // Real type is <?>
    int result;

    ComputableInfo(String id) {
        computable = ComputableFactory.createFrom(id);
        configureAndCompute(computable);
    }

    private <T> void configureAndCompute(IComputable<T> computable) {
        T typedConfig = computable.configure();
        this.config = typedConfig;
        this.result = computable.compute(typedConfig);
    }
}
```

This works and does not require making `ComputableInfo` generic.

If you need to capture the type for longer than a single method, e.g. if you want to use the created `config` multiple times, you can use encapsulation:

```java
class ComputableInfo {
    static final class CompState<T> {
        IComputable<T> computable;
        T config;

        CompState(IComputable<T> c) {
            computable = c;
        }
        private void configure() {
            config = computable.configure();
        }
        private int compute() {
            return computable.compute(config);
        }
    }
    CompState<?> state;
    int result;

    ComputableInfo(String id) {
        state = new CompState<>(ComputableFactory.createFrom(id));
        state.configure();
        result = state.compute();
    }
}
```

That way, you still avoid exporting the type parameter to users of `ComputableInfo`.

Comment: I ended up using the `State<T>` class "trick": indeed, where `<T>` has a meaning for the Computable, we need to move the logic inside a generic.

Comment: @Holger ... or use a raw type, like `Collections::reverse` does, which is ugly, imho.

Comment: @Eugene `Collections::swap` was what I had in mind; I just simplified it for this answer. Both methods even contain a comment (in the OpenJDK version) mentioning that a “supplementary private method” would be an alternative to using a raw type. I suppose, for the core classes that are used in cold code paths during the initialization, avoiding such a delegation is ok, but that’s nothing, application code should copy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a lower-bounded wildcard. The `Object` is not compliant with a wildcard `?` itself.

```
class ComputableInfo {
    IComputable<? super Object> computable;
    Object config;
    int result;

    ComputableInfo(String id) {
         computable = null;
         config = computable.configure();
         result = computable.compute(config);
    }
}
```

---

A lower bound states that `IComputable` will be an instance of `Object` or an instance of some object being a superclass of `Object` (which actually the object is a parent of all `Objects`). For the better understanding, let's use rather `Number`:

```
IComputable<Integer> computableInteger = ...;
IComputable<Number> computableNumber = ...;
IComputable<Object> computableObject = ...;

IComputable<? super Number> computableSuperNumber = ...;
computableSuperNumber = computableInteger;                  // doesn't compile
computableSuperNumber = computableNumber;                   // ok
computableSuperNumber = computableObject;                   // ok
```

---

However, it is safe to pass an `Integer` or `Double` into a method of that instance through. In a snippet below `computableSuperObject`  references an `IComputable` that could be one of:

- `IComputable<Number>`
- `IComputable<Object>`.

Since the reference *might* be `IComputable<Number>`, computing with `Object` is illegal as long it doesn't fit there as long as `Object` can be ex. `String`.

```
IComputable<? super Number> computableSuperNumber = ...;

Integer integer = 1;
Double d = 1d;
Number number = 1;
Object object = 1;                     // the Object can be also "string", see below
Object objectString = "string";
String string = "string";

computableSuperNumber.compute(integer);                     // ok
computableSuperNumber.compute(d);                           // ok
computableSuperNumber.compute(number);                      // ok
computableSuperNumber.compute(object);                      // doesn't compile
computableSuperNumber.compute(objectString);                // doesn't compile
computableSuperNumber.compute(string);                      // doesn't compile
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, in your first example, you state that `computableSuperNumber = computableInteger` doesn't compile but `computableSuperNumber = computableObject` does. Isn't it the other way around?

Comment: The snippet is correct (try to compile by yourself). The lower/upper bounds wildcards concept is confusing at the first glance and takes a while to understand. `IComputable<? super Number>` is either `IComputable<Number>` or `IComputable<Object>`, therefore `computableSuperNumber = computableInteger;` doesn't compile. When you call a method with a wildcard parameter, you need to get sure that passed type is compliant, therefore passing `Integer`, `Double` (subtypes of `Number`) and the `Number` itself is okey, while `String` or `Object` is not.

Comment: OK, thanks. I need to wrap it around my head for a while before it gets in ;)

Comment: When you have an `IComputable<? super Number>`, you can pass a `Number` or any supertype of it to the `compute` method, but on the other hand, you can not expect to get a `Number` back from `configure`. The construct `IComputable<? super Object>` is even weirder, it happens do work, as there is only one actual compatible type you could implement, `IComputable<Object>` (or yo you know other supertypes of `Object`), so it’s basically not different to throwing away the benefits Generics. The assignable `IComputable` implementations must accept any `Object` in their `compute` method…