# Mockito in maven using JPMS cannot access a member of class with modifiers "private"

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, java-platform-module-system

I am migrating a codebase to Java 11 and JPMS / Jigsaw and am having some trouble with mocking.

This is the test I am trying to run.

```
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Captor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class DbTest {

    @Mock
    private Connection connection;

    @Mock
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Timestamp> dateCaptor;

    @Test
    public void setTimestamp_instant() throws SQLException {
        Instant inputTime = Instant.parse("2018-03-12T10:25:37.386Z");
        when(connection.prepareStatement(anyString())).thenReturn(preparedStatement);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE fakeTable SET time = ? WHERE TRUE");
        RowPack rowPack = new RowPack(preparedStatement, DatabaseType.MYSQL);
        rowPack.setTimestamp(inputTime);
        verify(preparedStatement).setTimestamp(anyInt(), dateCaptor.capture(), Mockito.any(Calendar.class));
    }
}
```

When running this test in Eclipse it passes but when I run it through maven it fails due to mockito being unable to find some resources using reflection.

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Problems setting field connection annotated with @org.mockito.Mock(name="", stubOnly=false, extraInterfaces={}, answer=RETURNS_DEFAULTS, serializable=false, lenient=false)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.mockito.internal.util.reflection.ReflectionMemberAccessor cannot access a member of class foo.bar.DbTest (in module foo.bar) with modifiers "private"
```

I am using Surefire 3.0.0-M5, junit 5.7.0 and mockito 3.5.10.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Needless to say this worked well in maven before switching to modularising with JPMS.

I have read [Testing in the modular world](https://sormuras.github.io/blog/2018-09-11-testing-in-the-modular-world.html) and tried the junit-platform-maven-plugin as a replacement for surefire but ran into similar problems with mockito.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply based on the thing that testing private things does not make sense...only test public interfaces... and yes module prevent that cause it's harder then private/protected/package etc. in the general Java world

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***TL;DR*** — You need to configure the Surefire Plugin to pass the [*`--add-opens`*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781) option to *`java`* when it runs your test…

> > #### [*--add-opens*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-12F945EB-71D6-46AF-8C3D-D354FD0B1781)
> >
> > *If you have to allow code on the class path to do **deep reflection** to access nonpublic members, then use the `--add-opens` runtime option.*
> >
> > *Some libraries do deep reflection, meaning `setAccessible(true)`, so they can access all members, including private ones. You can grant this access using the `--add-opens` option on the `java` command line…*

---

Although I wasn't able to reproduce 100% verbatim the error message in your question, I was able to produce one that was pretty much the same. It was similar enough to yours, that I'm confident that the root cause (*and the solution*) of both mine and yours is the same.

[*In this demo that you can download and build*](https://github.com/deduper/mockito.jpms.solution.demo), I resolved the error I got with…

```xml
…
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        …
        <argLine>add-opens foo.bar/foo.bar=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
        …
    </configuration>
</plugin>
…
```

[*Download and build the demo*](https://github.com/deduper/mockito.jpms.solution.demo). Feel free to modify it however you see fit.

Comment: This solved my issue, thanks.
It's a bummer that it forces a separate surefire configuration for each project but I guess that can't be helped.

Comment: „*This solved my issue, thanks*“ – @oscar.haglund — You're welcome. My main goal in contributing to SO is my own continuous improvement. To that end, I'm desperate to learn: *In what way could my answer be improved in order for you to have marked it as accepted?*. Or upvoted even? Your comment suggests my answer helped you. So please can you help *me* now, by answering *my* question? [*Which I've asked before*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926746/4465539), to no avail. – „*…it forces a separate surefire configuration for each project…*“ — That's because each project has different needs. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to configure the maven-surefire-plugin with `<useModulePath>false</useModulePath>`, which will stop enforcing modular access control.

Caution: This will make your tests run on the classpath. Usually, you want tests to run in as similar an environment as possible to that at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to place an own `module-info.java` inside the test sources (`src/test/java` in Maven) specifying `open` (See [Allowing runtime-only access to all packages in a module](https://www.oracle.com/de/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)) for the test module with the following contents:

```java
// "open" seems to be the magic word: it opens up for reflective access
// the same module name like for the main module must be used, so the main module has also the name "com.foo.bar"
open module com.foo.bar {
// I use still juni4
    requires junit;
// require Mockito here
    requires org.mockito;
// very important, Mockito needs it
    requires net.bytebuddy;
// add here your stuff
    requires org.bouncycastle.provider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I am using Junit and Mockito on a Java 11 jpms project and wanted to run my tests using maven.

To build upon deduper's great answer, I added:

```
<configuration>
    <argLine>--add-opens foo.bar/foo.bar=ALL-UNNAMED</argLine>
</configuration>
```

on my surefire configuration.

Notice the 2 prefixed dashes **--**, without them add-opens was parsed as a class and throws an Error.