# Spring NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when switching to JPMS (Java Platform Module System)

Tags: java, spring, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I am trying to migrate a large project to JPMS (Java Platform Module System).

It contains some Spring components that are giving me some trouble.
I have created a [test repo](https://github.com/oscarhaglund/spring-jpms-test) to demonstrate the issue. When I remove the module-info.java file it works just fine as shown by the test in [TestControllerTest.java](https://github.com/oscarhaglund/spring-jpms-test/blob/main/src/test/java/com/spacemetric/spring/jpmstest/TestControllerTest.java#L60). However, if I add the module-info.java then it stops working with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'RESTConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest.auth.FooAuthenticationProvider' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at spring.beans@5.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
at spring.beans@5.2.6.RELEASE/org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)
at …
```

The stack trace seems to indicate that the `ApplicationContext` is unable to find the `@Autowired` implementation. I have opened the entire module for deep reflection. My highly uneducated guess is that this might be related to the classpath versus modulepath but I am at a loss for what to do about it.

The module-info.java file is as follows:

```
open module com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest {       
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires spring.security.config;
    requires spring.security.web;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires spring.security.core;
    requires javax.servlet.api;
    requires spring.web;
}
```

The following is the command line used by Eclipse to run the test (as requested):

> C:\Program
> Files\Java\java-11-openjdk-11.0.7.10-1.windows.redhat.x86_64\bin\javaw.exe
> -ea --add-opens com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest/com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest=ALL-UNNAMED
> --add-modules=ALL-MODULE-PATH -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p "C:\dev\source\spring-jpms-test\target\classes;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\5.3.2.RELEASE\spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\5.3.2.RELEASE\spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\5.3.2.RELEASE\spring-security-config-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\3.1.0\javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar"
> -classpath "C:\Users\Oscar Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-jcl-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-expression-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-engine\5.7.0\junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\apiguardian\apiguardian-api\1.1.0\apiguardian-api-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-engine\1.7.0\junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\opentest4j\opentest4j\1.2.0\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-commons\1.7.0\junit-platform-commons-1.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\junit\jupiter\junit-jupiter-api\5.7.0\junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\5.2.6.RELEASE\spring-test-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\restdocs\spring-restdocs-mockmvc\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-restdocs-mockmvc-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar Haglund.m2\repository\org\springframework\restdocs\spring-restdocs-core\2.0.5.RELEASE\spring-restdocs-core-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.9.5\jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.9.0\jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.9.5\jackson-core-2.9.5.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-junit-jupiter\3.5.10\mockito-junit-jupiter-3.5.10.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\mockito\mockito-core\3.5.10\mockito-core-3.5.10.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.10.13\byte-buddy-1.10.13.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy-agent\1.10.13\byte-buddy-agent-1.10.13.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\objenesis\objenesis\3.1\objenesis-3.1.jar;C:\Users\Oscar
> Haglund.m2\repository\org\junit\platform\junit-platform-launcher\1.7.0\junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\dev\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\259\0.cp;C:\dev\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\257\0.cp"
> --patch-module "com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest=C:\dev\source\spring-jpms-test\target\test-classes"
> --add-reads com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest=ALL-UNNAMED org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner -version 3
> -port 55245 -testLoaderClass org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader
> -loaderpluginname org.eclipse.jdt.junit5.runtime -classNames com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest.TestControllerTest

Comment: [*Your README*](https://github.com/oscarhaglund/spring-jpms-test/commit/52c6e6cf81f317d63d01e3a1e735dd38adf92617#diff-04c6e90faac2675aa89e2176d2eec7d8R6) talks about a module-info.java for „*The test class*“. Questions: (***1***) *What is your use case that you need to have a module-info.java in your test directory?* (***2***) *What command should be run to produce the error?* (***3***) *Is this related at all to* [*your other JPMS issue*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64120676/mockito-in-maven-using-jpms-cannot-access-a-member-of-class-with-modifiers-priv/64129859#64129859)? TIA.

Comment: „*…The stack trace seems to indicate that the ApplicationContext is unable to find the @Autowired implementation…*“ — You've guessed incorrectly, I'm afraid. By the time you come back to me with answers to my questions, I might be in a position to elaborate on what I mean. TIA.

Comment: (1) Apologies for the unclear readme. The module-info.java is for the source directory (src/main/java) and the minimal implementation I have created to showcase the exception I am getting in a much larger project. The readme refers to the unit test that can be run to produce the exception.
(2) Run the unit test class in your IDE of choice. I have updated the original text to include the command used by Eclipse to run the test. 
(3) Only in as so far they have both occurred trying to convert the same repository. The issues occurred in different modules.

Comment: „*(1)…The module-info.java is for the source directory (src/main/java)…*“ — Maybe @Eugene might not have jumped to the wrong conclusion in his answer if your README read: „*…TestControllerTest runs successfully if the module-info.java file is removed **from `src/main/java`***“ — „*…(2) Run the unit test class in your IDE…*“ — That's another revelation. You never mentioned an IDE originally. I built your MRE from a terminal. The test succeeded —  „*…the command used by Eclipse to run the test…*“ — What are the ***Eclipse menu option steps*** to reproduce the error? You're new. You'll learn. TIA

Answer (score 1):

First of all put the `module-info.java` in `src/main/java`, not in `src/test/java`. Also I have slightly changed it to:

```
module spring.jpms.test {
   requires spring.core;
   requires spring.context;
   requires spring.beans;
   requires spring.security.config;
   requires spring.security.web;
   requires spring.webmvc;
   requires spring.security.core;
   requires javax.servlet.api;
   requires spring.web;

   opens com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest;

}
```

But anyway, this solves only "partially" because:

Welcome to a rather crude reality of `modules` and `spring` (or tools in general). Have a look [here, where people have the same problems](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21515). The only viable solution I found is to do :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <useModulePath>false</useModulePath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works with `mvn clean install` (and `junit5`), I haven't tried or played enough with `intellij` to make it work.

Comment: What's the rationale for undoing *`open module…`*? Your *`opens com.spacemetric.spring.jpmstest`* advice assumes you already know (*without asking*) that the *real* project has only the 1 pkg. It might have 10 and needs to open them all. In that use case, *`open module…`* is simpler. You assume the OP's use case doesn't require tests be in the main module? Based on what? I've asked @oscar.haglund to clarify his use case. But until he replies, any advice is premature and uninformed. — „*…rather crude reality of modules…*“ — Or even a *cruel* reality. Both are rather *sophisticated* IMHO. TIA.