# Spring Security + Keycloak Authorization: How to associate an endpoint with a Resource?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, authorization, keycloak

I have created a Spring Boot app with `spring-boot-starter-security` and `keycloak-spring-security-adapter` and authenticating users with Keycloak works as intended.

I now want to use Keycloak's [Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_overview) for fine-grained access control to my API.

In Keycloak, I've enabled Authorization for my client. I've created a Role and I've assigned the Role to my test User. I've created a Resource and a Resource-based Permission and I've added a Role-based Policy. Using the Evaluate feature, I've confirmed, that my user has permission to access my resource.

[image]

Let's say I have the following controller with one endpoint.

```
@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun getPatientInfo(principal: Principal): String {
        return "Hello, ${principal.name}!"
    }
}
```

Now my question is: How do I associate an endpoint in my Spring Boot application with the given Resource so that the permission is evaluated when a request is made?

Comment: A few Qs for you, please, if you don't mind? (***1***) What have you tried so far? (***2***) If what you've tried so far results in errors, what *precisely* is the error message? (***3***) What versions of Spring Boot, Keycloak, JDK, etc. are you using? (***4***) What OS is your app deployed on? (***5***) What build tool — *if any* — do you build your app with? (***6***) Any other details you imagine might be helpful for somebody helping you to reproduce any failures you're observing? (***7***) Can you share an [*MRE*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please? TIA

Answer (score 0):

> „*…How do I associate an endpoint in my Spring Boot application with the given Resource so that the permission is evaluated when a request is made?…*“

By way of example, let's say…

- Your Keycloak server is running on port 8585
- Your application server is running on port 8080
- Your realm is named „*`myrealm`*“
- Your resource is named „*`my-client-resource`*“
- You role is named „*`super-user`*“

Then in your Spring Boot application's *application.properties* file you'd set…

```yaml
#port on which the application would run
server.port = 8080
keycloak.realm = myrealm
keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8585/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = none
#keycloak resource is the client ID
keycloak.resource = my-client-resource
keycloak.use-resource-role-mappings = true
keycloak.public-client = true
…
# Configures what ${principal.name} will return
keycloak.principal-attribute=preferred_username
```

And you hook into Spring Boot's Keycloak configuration with…

```java
…
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
@ComponentScan( basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class )
public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
        super.configure( http );
    
        http.authorizeRequests( )
            .antMatchers( "/hello", "…" )
            .hasRole( "super-user" )
            .anyRequest( )
            .permitAll( );
    }
…
}
```

In the absence of more specific details of your application and configuration, the above is a *sketch*. But that is the general approach.

For a more concrete grasp of the above general approach, [*download and play with this MRE*](https://github.com/deduper/springboot.keycloak.mre) that I implemented [*for another answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64109416) recently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the unspecific question. Is there a way to have multiple endpoints and have each endpoint be associated to a different resource?

Comment: „*…have multiple endpoints and have each endpoint be associated to a different resource?…*“– @KirillRakhman — Yes. Each resource can have its own rootUrl, redirecUris, etc. As another ***general*** example of what's possible, search for „*If you have multiple deployments*“ in the doc's „[*Securing WARs via Adapter Subsystem*](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/securing_apps/#securing-wars-via-adapter-subsystem)“ section. But let me stress this: *I'm not proposing what's  on that page as a solution to your **specific** requirement. I'm only pointing at that   as a general thing Keycloak can do*.

Comment: Maybe I have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) then and I should formulate my question more broadly. How can I apply different permissions to different endpoints to implement a Role-based access control? I don't care if it's done via resources or not but `hasRole('admin')` isn't sufficient as it checks for roles, not permissions.

Comment: „*Maybe I have an XY Problem*“ — I honestly can't say. But I do agree with the ***What to do about it?*** part:  „(***1***) *…include information about…any attempted solution…* (***2***) *If someone asks for more information, do provide details…*“ — „*…but `hasRole('admin')` isn't sufficient as it checks for roles, not permissions…*“ — Thanks for ruling that out. I'll play around with *Resource-based Permissions*  and edit my answer accordingly. In the meantime, please see the ***7*** requests for more information I submitted in the comments yesterday? TIA.

Comment: @KirillRakhman the policy enforcer via the Keycloak adapter does all that for you. You do not need to declare the RBAC in Spring Security builder. Therefore; perform all your definitions in Keycloak policies and resources. 

@deduper answer is still right if you remove `.andMatchers(...).hasRole(...)`